# php preg_match closing </b>

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
if(preg_match('/<div class="item"><b>(.+)</b><br>/', $html, $habbo)) {
```

But I get this error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'b' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Jvdw\activeer.php on line 6
```

Because `</b>` close the regex.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using / as a delimiter. I recommend using another character for that:

`preg_match('~<div class="item"><b>(.+)</b><br>~', $html, $habbo)`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

What the regex interprets is this: `'/<div class="item"><b>(.+)</b'`, because the / is used to stop and start the regex. In this case it tries to us the b as a modifier which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx engine thinks that, RegEx is over at `</` in `</b>`. You can escape it, with a `\` like this

```
<\/b>
```